# Assign height property to option tag

Tags: css, tags, height

I need to set a bigger height for the option tags inside my select.

```
<select name="forms" id="forms">
    <option value="1">Row 1</option>
    <option value="1">Row 1</option>
    <option value="1">Row 1</option>
</select>
```

I used the CSS code below for this purpose, but it did not work.

```
option {
   padding-top:5px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Also I have tested this one, and again, anything happened.

```
option {
    height:20px;
}
```

What is your suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly Graphicdivine? What should I have considered about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could set a certain height for it using a style for the select tag:

```
<select name="" style="height:25px">
```

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `select` often uses built-in routines that are immune to CSS. This is why both methods fail on many browsers. On Firefox, they both work. The same seems to apply to any indirect methods one might try (line-height, font-size).